# Total Hours Format in Moment.js

Tags: datatables, momentjs, datetime-format

I'm creating a data table using DataTables.net where a column contains the cumulative running hours of an event. I'm simply adding to the hours each time, so I have for example:

`40:34:30`

which is 40 hours, 34 minutes, 30 seconds.

My problem is I want to order this column by hours, and I haven't been able to find anything that supports this from Moment.js. Ideally I imagine it would be something like "HHH:mm:ss", or something like that. As it stands, the column recognises the fields as strings, so 0:12:34 is appearing above anything else in descending order despite only being 12 minutes long.

Comment: y r u using moment.js here?

Comment: It's the plugin used for sorting Date time formats for Data Table: https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

Answer (score 1):

You can sort **HH:mm:ss** by re-formating it to **seconds** before sorting.

```
moment.duration('40:34:30').asSeconds;
```

gives you *146070*. Then simply use seconds in your sorting script.

here is the solution: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fom8nnv9/)

And if you *really* need just the hour part; use `Math.floor`: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fom8nnv9/2/)

Comment: I will get round to trying this when I can, but this seems to be an alternative that would work to what I'm trying now thanks